# What is the Web Thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

Due to some self induced problems, I was able to crash my iPhone app and received the following error:

`Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...`

Resolving this problem isn't an issue, but the error message got me thinking...

I know what the main thread is, and I'm aware of how to switch contexts back to it. But, what is this "web thread"? I don't think I've ever heard that terminology before.

Comment: Not at all familiar with iPhone dev; it seems it would be the thread responsible for any HTTP/WS calls. In the web world I would envision this as the thread which makes calls to varying services (WS/Database) before heading back to the application and thus the main thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web thread is a single thread shared by all `UIWebViews` which temporarily blocks execution on the main thread while it's performing requests.

Comment: Interesting...so work is spun off on another thread; yet it blocks execution on a differing thread...that seems counter-intuitive to threading. No mobile experience speaking here...

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what advantage does this serve? I usually spin up my own thread (especially with GCD now) and just perform network I/O there... It does seem odd to have a whole thread that LOCKS the UI thread while doing networking...

Comment: @Aaron: I agree. I'm not sure what the advantage to spawning another thread is when you block the main thread, but you can see [other people have had issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431594/avoid-main-thread-freezes-when-uiwebview-tries-to-blockingly-lock-the-web-thread) with such things.

Comment: According to the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431594/avoid-main-thread-freezes-when-uiwebview-tries-to-blockingly-lock-the-web-thread?noredirect=1&lq=1 the web thread doesn't block the main thread necessarily, but, many UIKit methods attempt to get a lock on it from the main thread, so it can easily lead to the main thread blocking on it.