# how can I change html in UIWebView by javascript and capture screenshot of the updated webview. Can it be achieved by CGD?

Tags: javascript, ios, multithreading, uiwebview, grand-central-dispatch

I am using a UIWebView to display a web page, I want to hide some elements in the webpage, and take a screen shot of that page, after I get the image, I will unhide the elements to make webView back to normal.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
NSString * result1 = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(function(){document.getElementById(\"bottom-bar\").style.display = 'none';return document.getElementById(\"bottom-bar\").style.display;})();"];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, NO, 0.0);
        {
            CGPoint savedContentOffset = webView.scrollView.contentOffset;
            CGRect savedFrame = webView.scrollView.frame;

            webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
            webView.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);

            [webView.scrollView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            webView.scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
            webView.scrollView.frame = savedFrame;
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSString * result2 = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"bottom-bar\").style.display = 'block';"];
```

I cannot get the image I want.

what I have got is the image of the original webview, which didn't hide the element.

From the console, I got the right result, which is `"none"` and `"block"`, and the `"bottom-bar"` did flash on my screen.

Is there some background thread or queue when webview executing `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` or `renderInContext` is executing. How can I get the precise result.

UPDATED:Can I get the image by GCD and Blocks? As I know, webView executes js on webThread and update UI on main thread. So can I wait until webView updated its UI and capture the screen I want? Can I get notified from webTheard when webThread finished something.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, internal `UIWebView` work is done on the `WebThread`, not on the main app thread. I guess you could solve this problem in two ways:

1. Delay the screen capture with something like `dispatch_async` so it gets called after the HTML element gets hidden.
2. Do a callback to native from JavaScript after hiding your element. Add a fake location change to the end of the first JavaScript call.

`window.location.href='app://captureScreenShot';`

Then capture that request in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` delegate method, do your screen shot stuff and finally cancel the request.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSURL *url = request.URL;
if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"app"] && [url.host isEqualToString:@"captureScreenShot"]) {
    // Capture screenshot here
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

}

This way you're sure the screen shot code will always run after the JavaScript code executed.

Comment: I got result1 and result2 returned by JavaScript method. Seems webview didn't update UI. Can u explain a little about how web thread worked?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316154/what-is-the-web-thread It's just a thread shared by all the `UIWebViews`. But since it's a different thread the synchronous code from your post won't work. You either have to delay it (my suggestion 1) or do it asynchronously (my suggestion 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a javascript function to the webview writing it as a NSString.

Here an example:

```
int zoom = 10;
NSString *zoomString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", zoom];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:zoomString];
```

[This code can be useful for the screenshot](https://github.com/PabloAlejandro/UIImageUtils/blob/master/UIImageUtils/UIImageUtils/UIImage%2BScreenshot.m)